# How can I pull metadata for an object in a S3 bucket using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

I am wondering how I could pull metadata for an object in an S3 bucket. I am using AWS SDK for .NET. I already know how to pull a list of objects but I need to know how to pull metadata for each objects. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

```
using (var amazonClient = new AmazonS3Client())
{
      var getObjectMetadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest() { BucketName = RawBucketName, Key = fileName };
}
```

methods
link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Model_GetObjectMetadataRequest.htm

Comment: Thank you! I think the link is invalid.